# regex match 0);

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
SOMETHING(.*?),(1|0)\\);
```

It needs to match SOMETHING then anything, then a comma, then 1 or 0 followed by ); but for some reason the last bracket isn't being matched, an example string:

> SOMETHINGdfsdfdsfd dsffdsdf dfsfds FEHEF777a **,0);**

the bold part is the ending. Am I escaping the ) wrong? \ should work...

example php where $o is my string

```
preg_match_all('%INSERT INTO (.*?),(1|0)\);%sm', $o, $matches);
```

Comment: I tried it in RegexBuddy and it works for me. How are you using it?

Comment: As Martin notes, please post the code where this is being used.  Also, note what programming language you're using.

Comment: edited my post to incl php im using

Comment: You probably need to escape the backslash: `'%INSERT INTO (.*?),(1|0)\\\);%sm'`

Comment: Please, show an example of the actual input.  This works just fine using your original, artificial example.

Comment: Actual input is required indeed, as right now, it just plain works. I suspect the `;` is not there, as it isn't needed on queries, but lets find out.

Comment: Hmmm, or the op misses /i, it's all a guessing game.

Comment: I think you may need |()| encasing your regex so it's not read as a string. try |((.*?),[01]\);)|

Comment: @fy-tide The regex is delimited correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your original post doesn't show you are escaping it. You need:

```
SOMETHING(.*?),(1|0)\);
```

If you have that, what is the language running the regular expression, e.g. Java, PHP, Perl?

#### UPDATE

There are some things to consider. You are using a non-greedy expression in your first capture. In combination with your modifiers (multiline and dot all) this could be conflicting. Furthermore, based on your input you may need to escape the first set of parenthesis.

Regular Expressions are very powerful, but only as powerful as their creators. That is to say they often fail unless you know exactly what you are wanting to match.

Comment: seems markdown broke it, a user fixed my post. yes, i am escaping the bracket.

Comment: Yes, 't was hidden in the source ;)

Comment: +1 - this works for me, the only thing I would do different is change the "1|0" to a "[10]".

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes it non-greedy?

Comment: `.*?` is a non-greedy match of *anything*. Specifically the `?` suffix. Same for `.+?`

Comment: OIC, thanks.  (As it turns out, it would've been a quick search to confirm my assumption.)

Answer (score 1):

It does work here, did you maybe mean to get the ending `);` in there? If so:

```
 SOMETHING(.*?),((?:1|0)\);)
```

Otherwise: what language are we talking about? Do you need to double or triple the `\`? (`\\` / `\\\` can be possible in some implementations).

Edit: OK, php

```
$php -r 'var_dump(preg_match_all("/SOMETHING(.*?),(1|0)\);/","SOMETHINGdfsdfdsfd dsffdsdf dfsfds FEHEF777a ,0);",$matches),$matches);'
int(1)
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(49) "SOMETHINGdfsdfdsfd dsffdsdf dfsfds FEHEF777a ,0);"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
        [0]=>
    string(36) "dfsdfdsfd dsffdsdf dfsfds FEHEF777a "
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Perfect match.

Comment: Keep in mind, you removed the user's modification flags. Which I believe is the problem ;)

Comment: Nah, tested those, just not in output. Added newlines and extra commas and all in combination with /sm. Splurged with `0)` at other positions not followed by `;`, Still matches.

Comment: And I did not remove them, failed to add them when finally the language became available :)